# PHP Wont Extract zip file on windows ER_OPEN

Tags: php, windows, zip

I'm building a module installer for my CMS and i have ran into a problem now im using Windows 7 x64 with XAMPP x32 installed,

For some reason PHP returns the ER_OPEN error code (11) when ever i run my code and i know the directoy is writeable as the file gets move to the parent by php when it's uploaded here is my script

```
if($_URL['form'] == 'sent'){
            $target_path = getcwd()."\\..\\Temp-uplds\\";
            $target_path = $target_path. time() . basename( $_FILES['installFile']['name']); 

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['installFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
                $zip = new ZipArchive;
                $status = $zip->open('$target_path');
                if ($status === TRUE) {
                    $zip->extractTo(getcwd()."\\..\\Temp-uplds\\zip\\");
                    $zip->close();
                } else {
                    print_r(array($status, $zip));
                }
            } else{
                $this->tmp_vars->error = true;
            }

        }

        echo "<pre>error codes ZIPARCHIVE::ER_EXISTS = '".ZIPARCHIVE::ER_EXISTS."'
        File already exists.
        ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INCONS = '".ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INCONS."'
        Zip archive inconsistent.
        ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INVAL = '".ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INVAL."'
        Invalid argument.
        ZIPARCHIVE::ER_MEMORY = '".ZIPARCHIVE::ER_MEMORY."'
        Malloc failure.
        ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOENT = '".ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOENT."'
        No such file.
        ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOZIP = '".ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOZIP."'
        Not a zip archive.
        ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OPEN = '".ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OPEN."'
        Can't open file.
        ZIPARCHIVE::ER_READ = '".ZIPARCHIVE::ER_READ."'
        Read error.
        ZIPARCHIVE::ER_SEEK = '".ZIPARCHIVE::ER_SEEK."' </pre>";
```

And my Given output is

```
Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => ZipArchive Object ( [status] => 0 [statusSys] => 0 [numFiles] => 0 [filename] => [comment] => ) )
```

Any help would be helpfull

Comment: echo your `$targetPath` and make sure the file **is** there

Comment: `$targetPath` is set as i said "as the file gets move to the parent by php" this says that the upload work and just to clarify the upload system works so the `$targetPath` is correct and set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have single quotes around '$target_path'.  Variable interpolation only works with double quotes.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: it's always the simplest of things that gets overlooked thanks